# Div has margin-right even when margin & padding value is 0

Tags: html, css

I have a containing div (#anniversary-container) with an img inside, but the div has a margin to the right. I used inspect element in Chrome, and it said there was no margin but it shows the orange space next to it. I'm trying to make the contact info sit to the right but it doesn't let me. I already tried setting margin:0 and padding:0.

The problem is under the welcome header, the div that has the picture that says celebrating 60 years of Catholic service.
See for yourself.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5m8Lk5vv/1/embedded/result/)

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="description" content="Saint Anthony Claret Catholic Church is a humble church in which Catholics from all over the city can come together and worship, confess or make use of our various services" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="saint, anthony, church, mass, confession, baptism, confirmation, wedding, matrimony, anaheim, california" />
        <meta http-equiv="author" content="Eduardo Pelaez" />
        <title>St. Anthony Catholic Church</title>
        <link href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="page">
            <div id="header">
                <img src="images/logo.png" width="860" height="241" alt="St. Anthony Claret logo" />
                <div id="nav">
                    <ul id="nav-ul">
                        <a href="index.html"><li>Home</li></a>
                        <a href="#"><li>Services</li></a>
                        <a href="#"><li>Groups & Ministries</li></a>
                        <a href="#"><li>Schedule</li></a>
                        <a href="#"><li>Contact</li></a>
                        <a href="#"><li>About</li></a>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- end #nav-ul -->
            </div><!-- end #header -->
            <div id="content">
                <div id="feature">
                    <img src="images/feature-img.jpg" width="1250" height="350" alt="Picture of our altar" id="feature-img" />
                </div><!-- end #feature -->
                <div id="col1">
                    <div class ="col1-sec sec" id="col1-sec1">
                        <h2>Welcome</h2>
                        <div id="anniversary-container">
                            <img src="images/anniversary-img.jpg" width="862" height="840" alt="Celebrating 60 years of Catholic service" id="anniversary-img" />
                        </div><!-- end #anniversary-container -->
                        <div id="contact-container">
                            <p>1450 E. La Palma Avenue, Anaheim, CA 92805-1551</p>
                            <p><span class="contact-text">Phone</span> 714-776-0270</p>
                            <p><span class="contact-text">Fax</span> 714-776-6022</p>
                            <p><span class="contact-text">Email</span> <a href="mailto:stanthonyclaret@yahoo.com">stanthonyclaret@yahoo.com</a></p>
                        </div><!-- end #contact-container -->
                    </div><!-- end #col1-sec1 -->
                    <div class="col1-sec sec" id="col1-sec2">
                        <h2>Clergy</h2>
                        <p><span class="clergy-header">Pastor</span></p>
                        <p>Rev. Bill Cao</p>
                        <p><span class="clergy-header">Parochial Vicars</span></p>
                        <p>Rev. Douglas Zavala</p>
                        <p>Rev. Benjamin D. Hoang</p>
                        <p><span class="clergy-header">Deacons</span></p>
                        <p>Mr. August Mones</p>
                        <p>Mr. Salvador S&aacute;nchez</p>
                    </div><!-- end #col1-sec2 -->
                    <div class="col1-sec sec" id="col1-sec3">
                        <h2>Office Hours</h2>
                        <p><span class="hours-text">Weekdays</span> 9:00 AM to 8:00 PM</p>
                        <p><span class="hours-text">Saturdays</span> 9:00 AM to 5:30 PM</p>
                        <p><span class="hours-text">Sundays</span> 9:00 AM to 12:30 PM</p>
                    </div><!-- end #col1-sec3 -->
                </div><!-- end #col1 -->
                <div id="col2">
                    <div class="col2-sec sec" id="col2-sec1">
                        <p><span class="sidebar-header">Mass Schedule</span></p>
                        <p><span class="mass-header">Sunday</span></p>
                        <p>06:30 AM - English</p>
                        <p>08:00 AM - Espa&ntilde;ol</p>
                        <p>09:30 AM - English</p>
                        <p>11:00 AM - English</p>
                        <p>12:30 PM - Espa&ntilde;ol</p>
                        <p>05:00 PM - Espa&ntilde;ol</p>
                        <p>06:30 PM - Espa&ntilde;ol</p>
                        <p><span class="mass-header">Saturday Vigil</span></p>
                        <p>05:00 PM - English</p>
                        <p><span class="mass-header">Monday-Friday</span></p>
                        <p>06:30 AM - English</p>
                        <p>08:30 AM - English</p>
                        <p><span class="mass-header">Saturday</span></p>
                        <p>08:00 AM - English</p>
                        <p><span class="mass-header">Friday</span></p>
                        <p>07:00 PM - Espa&ntilde;ol</p>
                        <p><span class="mass-header">Thursday</span></p>
                        <p>07:00 PM - Espa&ntilde;ol</p>
                        <p><span class="mass-header">Perpetual Help Novena Wednesdays</span></p>
                        <p>07:00 PM - English</p>
                    </div><!-- end #col2-sec1 -->
                    <div class="col2-sec sec" id="col2-sec2">
                        <p><span class="sidebar-header">Confessions</span></p>
                        <p><span class="confessions-header">Wednesdays</span></p>
                        <p>05:30 to 06:30 PM</p>
                        <p><span class="confessions-header">Saturdays</span></p>
                        <p>03:30 to 04:30 PM<br />or by appointment</p>
                    </div><!-- end #col2-sec2 -->
                    <div class="col2-sec sec" id="col2-sec3">
                        <p><span class="sidebar-header">May Fiesta Contests</span></p>
                        <p>Pie Baking Contest</p>
                        <div id="pie-contest">
                            <a href="http://stanthonyclaret.org/wp-content/uploads/fiesta/pie%20baking%20flyer.pdf"><img src="images/pie-contest.png" width="468" height="487" alt="Announcement for pie baking contest" /></a>
                        </div><!-- end #pie-contest -->
                        <p>Salsa Recipe Contest</p>
                        <div id="salsa-contest">
                            <a href="http://stanthonyclaret.org/wp-content/uploads/fiesta/salsa%20contest.pdf"><img src="images/salsa-contest.png" width="479" height="527" alt="Announcement for salsa recipe contest" /></a>
                        </div><!-- end #salsa-contest -->
                        <div id="karaoke-contest">
                            <a href="http://stanthonyclaret.org/wp-content/uploads/fiesta/Karaoke%20Flyer.pdf"><img src="images/karaoke-contest.png" width="405" height="475" alt="Announcement for karaoke contest" /></a>
                        </div><!-- end #karaoke-contest -->
                    </div><!-- end #col2-sec3 -->
                    <div class="col2-sec sec" id="col2-sec4">
                        <p><span class="sidebar-header">Links</span></p>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="http://www.ccoc.org/">Catholic Charities</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.rcbo.org/">Diocese of Orange</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://w2.vatican.va/content/vatican/en.html">The Holy See</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!-- end #col2-sec4 -->
                    <div class="col2-sec sec" id="col2-sec5">
                        <p><span class="sidebar-header">Financial Report</span></p>
                        <div id="financial-report">
                            <a href="http://stanthonyclaret.org/announcements-anuncios/"><img src="images/report.png" width="833" height="1069" alt="Cover for the report of our expenses" /></a>
                        </div><!-- end #financial-report -->
                        <p>Fiscal Year Ending</p>
                        <p>06.30.14</p>
                    </div><!-- end #col2-sec5 -->
                </div><!-- end #col2 -->
            </div><!-- end #content -->
            <div id="footer">
                <p>Copyright &copy; 2015 Saint Anthony Claret Catholic Church - All Rights Reserved</p>
            </div><!-- end #footer -->
        </div><!-- end #page -->
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;}
#content {
    overflow: auto;}
#nav, #feature, #footer {
    margin: 1%;}
#col1, #col2 {
    float: left;
    margin: 1%;}
#col1 {
    width: 62.6%;}
#col2 {
    width: 31.3%;
    margin-right: 0%;}
li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0.5em;}
#nav, #footer {
    padding: 0.5em 0;}
#feature, .sec {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    background-color: #efefef;} /* remove background color when completed */
/* end general styling */
#feature-img {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;}
/* end feature styling */
#anniversary-img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    float: left;}
#anniversary-container {
    height: 15em;
    width: 15em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;} /* make container proportionate to img */
#contact-container {
    width: 15em;
    float: right;} /* make element float inside #anniversary-container */
```

Comment: just remove the width of the `#anniversary-container`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said "I'm trying to make the contact info sit to the right but"

If you want image in right and the contact info in left. you need to take both in a parent div and add float left to image and right to contact div and clear both to the next div.

It will solve your problem.

See the solved one with

```
#anniversary-container
```

[JsDFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5m8Lk5vv/7/embedded/result)

Also noticed you are giving 800px height to the image it will take the full height and the  div will look weird.

One more thing Divs are block level elements, which means they always expand to 100% of the width of their container.

Comment: This was the real problem. I meant to add a parent div for both elements but used it for the img only.
I changed the size of the img in the CSS, would that override the height in the HTML?

Comment: did you added any height on body? as per the previous as you were using big image, the height was due to the image, in-case you need height; add min-height instead of giving height to the div

Answer (score 2):

**First,** there's really **no margin** in the `#anniversary-container`.

**Second,** you are using a `div` tag and a `div` tag is a **block element** which means it always occupy the entire **row space**.

**To solve the problem,** try adding `float: left;` to your `#anniversary-container` styles.

**Here's the [JsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/albertonaperijr/5m8Lk5vv/2/)**.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

It's because your container div is not floating. It will take up the entire line of you don't float it. Or use display:inline-block for both.

Answer (score 2):

Use float:left for anniversary-container div instead of img tag

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the   `width: 15em;` in `#anniversary-container` .

`#anniversary-container {

height: 15em;

**width: 15em;**

margin: 0;

padding: 0;

}`

If you remove it then you can see `anniversary-container` `div` occupy whole width.

[image: After Removing **width: 15em;**]